# DC component in the middle of the image using fftw

Tags: c++, fftw, dft

I want to know if it is possible to get the DC component in around the middle of the image using fttw library in C++. Sometimes it is preferable to centralize the spectrum by shifting the spectrum by M/2 vertically and N/2 horizontally so that the DC component and the low-frequency components are in the middle while the high-frequency components are around the four sides.

I looked in the documentation but they don't provide any information about that.

Best regard,

Comment: Just found the solution here: http://techdos.com/using-the-library-fftw-in-image-processing/

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. You would have to write your own shift algorithm. I have written an bunch of helper functions in my medical image reconstruction library here: https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/ft/DFT.hpp

Feel free to use as you like. There are also more robust filters like hann, hamming etc for artifact reduction and such.